# manage checkboxes with jquery and send those values in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

inside razor view I have two checbox properties. They are mutually exclusive. When one is selected other is not and vice versa.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Before)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start)
```

inside same view on dom ready I manage checkbox click

```
$('#Before').change(function () {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#Start').attr('checked', false);
        return;
     }   
     $('#Start').attr('checked', true);
});

$('#Start').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#Before').attr('checked', false);
        return;
    }
    $('#Before').attr('checked', true);
});
```

further I'm creating js object which will be stringified and sent to the mvc controller

```
var myObj= {            
      Before: $("#Before").is(':checked'),
      Start: $("#Start").is(':checked')      
};

 alert("Is before checked: "+$("#Before").is(':checked'));
 alert("Is start checked: "+$("#Start").is(':checked'));
/* This returns always selected (correct) value  */

$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          traditional: true,
          contentType: 'application/json',
          url: '/Home/Manage',
          data: JSON.stringify({ model: myObj}),              
          success: function (data) { }
          },error: function () {
              alert('error');
          }
});
```

and I have viewmodel which represent this myObj which is sent to the controller

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public bool Start { get; set; }
   public bool Before{ get; set; }
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(MyViewModel model)
{ 
}
```

Problem is following:

When Start is checked then I'm getting Start as checked and Before as non checked which is fine, but when Before is checked and Start is not than both are received inside controller in model as false.

Comment: If they are mutually exclusive, why not have one property and use radio buttons to make a selection?

Comment: I know that should be natural option to choose, but not an option in this situation.

Comment: What is `JSON.stringify({ model: myObj}),` returning when Before is checked?

Comment: You could also simplify this using `if ($("#Start").is(':checked')) { var data = { Start: "True" }} else { var data = { Before: "True" }}; $.post('@Url.Action("Manage", "Home")', data, function() {..});`

Comment: When you un/tick the checkboxes are they working correctly?

Comment: I have tested you code (fixed the syntax error on the `},error: function () {` line) and it works fine - the model is bound correctly. Note also in addition to the above suggestion, you can also simplify your `.change()` functions to simply `$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () { $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked')); })` (although you would need to wrap the 2 `EditorFor()` methods in a `<div>` if you have other checkboxes in the form so that the `.siblings()` selectors works correctly). Note also `traditional: true,` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.prop('checked', true);` instead of `.attr('checked', true);`

Comment: nope, problem remains. again both are false in controller, when Before is checked.

Comment: Are you recreate your "myObj" each time before send?

Comment: Maybe instead of `$("#Before").is(':checked')` try `$("#Before").prop('checked');`